# "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ContourGeneratorAlgorithm has been deleted" error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, runtimeerror

I have been doing this project for the last few weeks on QGIS 3.4 with no problems and now every time I try and go on it QGIS does not respond and it does not load. I clicked on another project which loaded fine and this error appeared:

> An error has occurred while executing Python code:
>
> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ContourGeneratorAlgorithm
> has been deleted  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/amy/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\contour\ContourGeneratorProvider.py",
> line 55, in loadAlgorithms
> self.addAlgorithm( alg ) RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ContourGeneratorAlgorithm has been deleted

Does this have something to do with my project is now not loading?

Not sure if it is to do with a plugin bug.

Comment: It's a plugin bug, in the "contour" plugin

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the plugin. The project file should be fine, don't worry. You can try and reinstall the plugin to get rid of the message.